# Salesforce callout failing with null input to json parser

Tags: salesforce, apex

In salesforce during callout with named credentials, I get the following error message:

```
Scheduled Callout Failed
```

And the causing exception is:

```
System.NullPointerException: null input to JSON parser
```

What might be going wrong? why is it trying to parse a json during callout?

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard "Scheduled Callout Failed" error message. It's something your colleague created.

You should put debug logging on the user who this is running as (scheduled job? Check in setup). Probably the call fails, returns null (empty body) and the code isn't handling it properly. You'd have to look what http status code the call returns. Maybe target server went down, maybe it rejects your password, API key expired, you didn't pay for something... Hard to say for sure. Check the debug log